# Access denied error when installing app on site collection for second time

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2015

I created an app for sharepoint and installed it on a site collection on my tenant. The app was working good at the begining. Later, I uninnstalled the app from the site collection and installed it again, but now I am getting the error **`Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.`** I also installed the app on other site collection, and the app seems to be working correctly. What is the problem? Why did it stop working?

The permissions the app has are :

```
**<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>**
```

I am installing the app with the tenant administrator user.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check both recycling bins and make sure that the app has been removed from there on the site collection that is having the problem?

Comment: Yes I did, but still didnt work. I also noticed the problem was fixed automatically after two days. Is this a regular behaviour from Sharepoint? Should I always wait that time to access again to the app?